# how to uninstall apps installed on non existing sdcard

Tags: applications, 5.1-lollipop, uninstallation, sony-xperia-z1

I've moved some apps on my lollipop to sdcard after I formated the sdcard I cannot uninstall those apps from the device they appears like this :

[image]

Comment: Did you tried just uninstalling it from app manager in settings?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Applications/Apps

Find the App you want to Uninstall, then Clear Data, and Clear Defaults, if any.

Try and Uninstall it.

Comment: I don't even know there name to look for them !

Comment: When you tap and hold on them do you get a button as "App info" or "Uninstall" ?

Comment: when I want to uninstall them from the menu I got App not found with button OK

Comment: Well then, you can perform factory reset, but probably there must be easier solution.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm looking for :/